# metpy complains file is invalid data

Tags: metpy

I am trying to use the example script [found here](https://unidata.github.io/MetPy/latest/examples/formats/NEXRAD_Level_2_File.html) to plot a nexrad level 2 file [from here](https://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/pub/data/nccf/radar/nexrad_level2/KIWX/) but I get an invalid data error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "F:\z0sh\py\NEXRAD_Level_2_File.py", line 28, in <module>
    f = Level2File( filename )
  File "F:\z0bin\python\py38\lib\site-packages\metpy\io\nexrad.py", line 177, in __init__
    self._buffer = IOBuffer.fromfile(fobj)
  File "F:\z0bin\python\py38\lib\site-packages\metpy\io\_tools.py", line 179, in fromfile
    return cls(fobj.read())
  File "bz2.py", line 182, in read
  File "_compression.py", line 103, in read
OSError: Invalid data stream
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is that while the files from that site have a `.bz2` extension, they are not valid bzip2-ed files. This is problem because based on the extension, MetPy assumes it should pass it to Python's `BZ2File` to open the file. MetPy really *should* be able to recover from this (just by opening the raw file), but can't--I've opened an [issue](https://github.com/Unidata/MetPy/issues/1341) to fix this.

For now, the work-around is to rename the file and remove the `.bz2` extension. So this works:

```
f = Level2File('KIWX_20200322_164108')
```

Comment: This is an issue in the weather-climate toolkit from NOAA as well. Now I know why!